# Передать в alert значение переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок, текст в который записывается через script.js

```
<div id="alert">  </div>
```

При загрузке страницы выводится системное сообщение с текстом из этого блока

```
alert($("#alert").html());
```

Получается что это системное сообщение загружается раньше скрипта script.js, и оно пустое.
Кто может подсказать, как загрузить script.js раньше, чтобы текст попал в alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну раз вы используете `jquery`, то весь функционал навешивайте внутри блока, вызываемого после загрузки страницы

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert($("#alert").html());
});
```